# Bernstein theorem on monotone functions. Nonbounded case

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Bernstein theorem on monotone functions states that bounded $C^\infty$ function $f(x) \colon (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies inqualities
$$
    (-1)^n \frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n} \geqslant 0
$$
for all $x >0$ and for any $n =0,1,\ldots$ if and only if there is a Borel nonnegative measure $\mu$ on $[0,+\infty)$ such that
$$
  f(x) = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha x} \mathrm \, d \mu(\alpha).
$$
Furthemore, $f(+0) = \mu \left([0,+\infty)\right)$ and measure $\mu$ is defined uniqely.

My question is if it is possible to remove the boundedness condition on function $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f$ is bounded, we have a  **finite** nonnegative measure $\mu$. Finiteness of $\mu$ is directly related to the boundedness of $f$, so giving up one we also give up the other. The following are equivalent:

- $f$ satisfies $(-1)^n \frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n} \geqslant 0$ for all $n\ge 0$ and all $x>0$
- there is a Borel nonnegative measure $\mu$ on $[0,+\infty)$ such that for all $x>0$ the integral $\int\limits_0^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha x} \mathrm \, d \mu(\alpha)$ converges and is equal to $f(x)$.

References:

1. *Bernstein Functions: Theory and Applications* by René L. Schilling, Renming Song, and Zoran Vondracek. [Google Books with preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=QVmHfZZQ0k0C). See Theorem 1.4.
2. *Convexity: An Analytic Viewpoint* by Barry Simon. [Google Books without preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=2IjtmAEACAAJ).