Finding functions $f(t)$ such that $(f(t))^{s}$ is a Bernstein function.
I'm studying Bernstein function from the book  R.L. Schilling, R. Song, and Z. Vondraček, Bernstein Functions: Theory and Applications, 2. ed (De Gruyter, Berlin, 2012).
Definition. A function $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a Bernstein function if $f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$,', $f(t)\geq 0$ for all $t>0$ and
\begin{align}
(-1)^{n-1}f^{(n)}(t)\geq 0,\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and } t>0
\end{align}
An example of a Bernstein function is $f(t)=t^s$ when $0\leq s\leq 1$. In general, is there a criterion for functions $f(t)$ such that $(f(t))^{s}$ with $0\leq s\leq 1$ let a Berstein function?. Thanks.

Please define Bernstein functions.

ok Now i wrote the definition

Bernstein function definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions , see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/362477/532409

Assume that $t\ge 0$, $f(t)> 0$, $0\le s\le 1$ and $n\ge 1$. By Faà di Bruno's formula, we have
$$
\frac{{{\rm d}^n }}{{{\rm d}t^n }}f^s (t) =\\ \sum\limits_{m_1  +  \ldots  + nm_n  = n} {\frac{{n!}}{{m_1 ! \cdots m_n !}}\frac{{\Gamma (s + 1)}}{{\Gamma (s + 1 - (m_1  +  \ldots  + m_n ))}}f^{s - m_1  -  \ldots  - m_n } (t)\prod\limits_{j = 1}^n {\left( {\frac{{f^{(j)} (t)}}{{j!}}} \right)^{m_j } } } .
$$
Since $m_1  +  \ldots  + m_n  \ge 1$, we find
$$
\frac{{\Gamma (s + 1)}}{{\Gamma (s + 1 - (m_1  +  \ldots  + m_n ))}} = ( - 1)^{m_1  +  \ldots  + m_n  + 1} \left| {\frac{{\Gamma (s + 1)}}{{\Gamma (s + 1 - (m_1  +  \ldots  + m_n ))}}} \right|.
$$
Assume that $f$ is a Bernstein function, i.e., $( - 1)^{j - 1} f^{(j)} (t) \ge 0$, for $j \ge 1$. Then, since $m_1  +  2m_2+\ldots  + nm_n  = n$, we have
$$
( - 1)^{n - 1} \frac{{{\rm d}^n }}{{{\rm d}t^n }}f^s (t) =\\ \sum\limits_{m_1  +  \ldots  + nm_n  = n} {\frac{{n!}}{{m_1 ! \cdots m_n !}}\left| {\frac{{\Gamma (s + 1)}}{{\Gamma (s + 1 - (m_1  +  \ldots  + m_n ))}}} \right|f^{s - m_1  -  \ldots  - m_n } (t)\prod\limits_{j = 1}^n {\left( {\frac{{\left| {f^{(j)} (t)} \right|}}{{j!}}} \right)^{m_j } } } \\ \ge 0.
$$
Thus, if $f$ is a non-negative Bernstein function, then so is $f^s$ provided $0\le s\le 1$.
